# Metro UI as a XPages theme

Tags: xpages

I would like to present XP application with Metro style UI.

I think of three unique styles:

1) App launcher (aka Navigator from LN client) showing boxed "links", what is common image of Metro: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Windows_8_Consumer_Preview_Start_Screen.png.

2) List (aka View) - scrollable bars representing documents in view: http://www.brianbondy.com/static/img/blogpost_135/screenshot-filepicker.jpg 
http://www.purplesquirrels.com.au/?p=940

3) Form - sorry, images of metro theme are not very common for this kind of usecase.

Options:

Wait for Dojo framework to include Metro styled mobile components (no signs of this plan at Dojo site).

Wait for IBM to include Metro on Extlib mobile themes (probably not going to happen).

Make own theme definition and/or controls (lot of work...)

Forget it, it is just waste of time.

Did any of you think about making metro.theme for XPages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I where you I would try to create it yourself. Its not that difficult. Its actualy a bunch of boxes ;) which is perfectly possible with html/css ( and thus with xpages ). The only thing you need to take or of is what to do after a user clicked on a box. I dont see the problem in creating it yourself...